# AngularJS - FAQ inside a modal (bug?)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Currently i'm developing a webapp with AngularJS for a giant company, and i'm trying to have a simple FAQ inside a modal.

In my localhost the FAQ it's working just fine (very similar to the original FAQ in angular documentation), but when i write exactly the same code inside a modal i'm getting a console error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addGroup'
```

Important to state that inside the modal my $scope.oneAtATime = true; it's being ignored, so basically even if i force it to be true

```
<accordion close-others="true">
```

It's always false.
This addGroup method is on the AngularJS library code.

Any ideas?

The HTML:

```
 <div class="modal__container__body">
        <div id="faq_accordion" ng-controller="AccordionController">
            <accordion close-others="true">
                <accordion-group heading="{{faq.title}}" ng-repeat="faq in faqs">
                    {{faq.content}}
                </accordion-group>
            </accordion>
    </div>

    </div>
```

The controller

```
lobby.controller("AccordionController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    $scope.oneAtATime = true;

    $scope.faqs = [
      {
        title: "Q1?",
        content: "A1"
      },
      {
        title: "Q2?",
        content: "A2"
      },
        {
        title: "Q3?",
        content: "A3"
        },

        {
            title: "Q4?",
            content: "A4"
        }


    ];
}]);
```

Please notice that in the above code i'm forcing close-others to be true, directly in the html tab.

Help?

Comment: can you make a plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem recently, change

```
 <div id="faq_accordion" ng-controller="AccordionController">
```

to

```
 <div id="faq_accordion" ng-controller="MyAccordionController">
```

That should fix it. You basically overwrote the plugin controller with your own. Don't forget to change the controller definition also, it's the part that's breaking it.

Comment: That solved the problem.
Also, if you want to "force" it to be "true" directly on the HTML you have to put double "", like "'true'" . Is a bug known by the angular community and should be fixed soon !